# Simulate users in a chat room (PHP, ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, chat, load-testing

Good day to all.

I created a moderated chat (each question/answer/whatever have to be moderated). Now my only problem is that I don't know a way to simulate lots of users that type something and after the post is moderated get a replay. So what I ask is if there is someway to simulate users typing something then press enter. (and for each some ajax to get the response). I can moderate whatever they type or if I can simulate a moderator is even better.

Thank you for help.

Comment: So you want to simulate users that ask questions and answer.. and each of those action you have to moderate by hand? I don't see the use of that...

Comment: If there was no use I wouldn't ask it. The use is that the chat is used for some guys that give advice in a video conference. They will not be able to answer all questions so the questions must be moderated.

Comment: Selenium? http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Isn't selenium used for recording actions then play them... im not sure? I take a look on it.

Comment: How about writing a multi-threaded script in python that grabs comments off twitter (API) then using POST/GET protocol submits 1) Typing... 2) (30 seconds later) the comment off twitter

Comment: Would it not be better to actually get a bunch of actual test users?

Comment: How about ApacheBench? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dynamic web testing tool that supports sample data injection - [Loadzen has a dynamic data feature](http://loadzen.com/plugin/attaching-dynamic-data/): so you would record your test using their Scenario Recorder, then you would generate sample data sets for each of the recorded GETS/POSTS and attach them to your recorded scenario.

This will effectively have the same effect as simulating loads of users sending and responding to each other with sample/dynamic data, you could mix the data sets to make sure that it's random on both the answerers and askers side.